# Perl - Can't call method "content_type" on an undefined value

Tags: perl

So, I got a PERL script I am trying to run, it start like this:

```
use strict;
use a;

use CGI 'param';
use URI::Escape;
use HTML::FromText 'text2html';
use XML::Simple;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Data::Dumper;
use URI::Escape;
use DBI;
use Tie::DBI;
use Digest::MD5 'md5_hex';
use MIME::Base64;
use Encode;

my $r = shift; $r->content_type("text/html; charset=utf-8"); my $tmp = a::tmp();
```

When it get's to the part where content_type() function is called, it fails with this error message:

```
Can't call method "content_type" on an undefined value at script.pl line 18.
```

Any ideas? I am kinda PERL newbie.

Comment: It might be confused that you're trying to pull values from `@_`.  Try `my $r=shift(@ARGV);`.

Comment: @JackManey : That's not the case here. `@_` is inside subs; since the `shift` is not inside any sub it will act on `@ARGV`. There is no need to make it explicit

Comment: @JackManey - not really, perldoc says _If ARRAY is omitted, shifts the `@_` array within the lexical scope of subroutines and formats, and the `@ARGV` array outside a subroutine_, see my answer.

Comment: We need to know more about the environment that you're trying to run this program in. Is it a CGI program, a mod_perl handler, or something completely different? What are you expecting $r to contain? What sort of object do you think it will be? Why do you expect to to have a `content_type` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `$r` is coming from `@ARGV`, it won't have a `content_type` method.

You could potentially `bless` `$r` into some package, but that's surely not what you're intending to do, here.

I'm guessing that you want to obtain a CGI parameter, probably a `POST`ed upload file? So you want `$r` to be a `CGI` object, not a parameter. You'd start with

```
 my $r = CGI->new;
```

But, then, I refer you to the very fine manual for `CGI`, http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html or `perldoc CGI` from the shell.

(To expand a bit:)

In Perl, a $scalar var holds "any one thing." Things coming in from the command-line are generally strings (maybe numbers, on a good day); that's what `shift` would get at the top level. (The special variable `@ARGV` contains command-line parameters passed in to your program.)

"One thing" can also be a reference to an object. In Perl's Object Oriented model, the *methods* of a *package* ("class") are tied to that reference using `bless`. That's usually handled for you, though; the special subroutine (aka function, method) `CGI::new` will create a new `CGI` object with some state data (things like form fields' values), and `bless` it into the `CGI` package.

The `->` notation going to a function call will only work if your variable contains a `bless`ed reference. You can "ask" what kind of a reference you have in a variable using `ref`; you'll get the name of its package (aka class). (`$foo = []; bless $foo => 'Some::Package'; print ref $foo;` => `Some::Package`)

— But, again, for your specific case, check out some of the examples in the `CGI` module's manual :-)

Comment: You're guessing wrong. `$r` is the customary name for the [RequestRec](http://p3rl.org/Apache2::RequestRec) object in mod_perl programming.

Comment: Oh, wow, hadn't thought of that :-D

If this is meant to be a `mod_perl` module, not a CGI script, then there's a whole other can of worms … like an entry point subroutine … ?

Answer (score 0):

[Perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) says:

> If ARRAY is omitted, shifts the @_ array within the lexical scope of
>   subroutines and formats, and the @ARGV array outside a subroutine (...)

This is second case (@ARGV) which seems to empty. Try dumping @ARGV to check its contents.

Comment: I'm almost certain that `@ARGV` won't contain a `bless`ed object reference, though :-)

Comment: @BRPocock it's possible to have `$r` there, but you are probably right ;) +1 for your answer.

Comment: I think I've probably stuffed things into `@ARGV` at some point in my life, but anybody doing `push @ARGV => CGI::new` on purpose needs a thorough spanking and no supper.